# How to index blob field in Apache Solr indexing?

Tags: apache, solr, indexing, dih

I am using Apache Solr to index my data, I have blob field which I want to be indexed too...but I dont know what is the fieldType to be declared in the 'scheme.xml'....

I tried following:

" field name="abstract" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" "

but when I tried to search then that field is shown as  :

id,   abstract,       title,        price,       publishedDate

1,    [B@1e9b7b2,  Spain Consumer,  3795.0,  2009-01-19T18:30:00Z

'abstract' is my blob filed which is nothing but big string...and I wanted text search on same field but when I indexed it then it is showing like this...
please suggest me what can I do?

thanking in advance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solr FAQ mentions this for the blob http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandlerFaq#Blob_values_in_my_table_are_added_to_the_Solr_document_as_object_strings_like_B.401f23c5

You can check for [searching-rich-format-documents-stored-dbms](http://www.lucidimagination.com/devzone/technical-articles/searching-rich-format-documents-stored-dbms)

There was an [JIRA issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-1348) for contributing the BlobTransformer, but doesn't seem to make it into the Code. You can refer the patch and pick the transformer for your use probably.

Not sure if its renamed/refactored/renamed differently in the Current versions.