# Indexing and querying BLOBS stored in Mysql

Tags: mysql, solr, indexing, blob

Greeting friends,

Straight to the point. I have stored many BLOBS in a Mysql DB. These are mainly PDF's(80%) and .doc. I have also text in the DB. Till now i have indexed and i can query the text, but i cannot index the BLOBS. I am trying to make a single collection(document)-but sucks. Is there any recipe on how to do such a thing?

**A portion of data-config.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<dataConfig>

<dataSource type="JdbcDataSource"
  autoCommit="true" batchSize="-1"
  convertType="false"
  driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
  url="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/ktimatologio"
  user="root"
  password="********"
  name="db"/>

<dataSource name="fieldReader" type="FieldStreamDataSource" />  

  <document> 

    <entity name="aitiologikes_ektheseis"
    dataSource="db"
    transformer="HTMLStripTransformer"
    query="select id, title, title AS grid_title, model, type, url, last_modified, CONCAT_WS('_',id,model) AS solr_id, search_tag, CONCAT( body,' ',title)  AS content from aitiologikes_ektheseis where type = 'text'"
    deltaImportQuery="select id, title, title AS grid_title, model, type, url, last_modified, CONCAT_WS('_',id,model) AS solr_id, search_tag, CONCAT( body,' ',title)  AS content from aitiologikes_ektheseis where type = 'text' and id='${dataimporter.delta.id}'"
    deltaQuery="select id, title, title AS grid_title, model, type, url, last_modified, CONCAT_WS('_',id,model) AS solr_id, search_tag, CONCAT( body,' ',title)  AS content from aitiologikes_ektheseis where type = 'text' and last_modified &gt; '${dataimporter.last_index_time}'">
      <field column="id" name="ida" />               
      <field column="solr_id" name="solr_id" />
      <field column="title" name="title" stripHTML="true" />
      <field column="grid_title" name="grid_title" stripHTML="true" />
      <field column="model" name="model" stripHTML="true" />
      <field column="type" name="type" stripHTML="true" />
      <field column="url" name="url" stripHTML="true" />
      <field column="last_modified" name="last_modified" stripHTML="true"  />
      <field column="search_tag" name="search_tag" stripHTML="true" />
      <field column="content" name="content" stripHTML="true" />
    </entity>

    <entity name="aitiologikes_ektheseis_bin"
    query="select id, title, title AS grid_title, model, type, url, last_modified, CONCAT_WS('_',id,model) AS solr_id, search_tag, bin_con AS text from aitiologikes_ektheseis where type = 'bin'"
    deltaImportQuery="select id, title, title AS grid_title, model, type, url, last_modified, CONCAT_WS('_',id,model) AS solr_id, search_tag, bin_con AS text from aitiologikes_ektheseis where type = 'bin' and id='${dataimporter.delta.id}'"
    deltaQuery="select id, title, title AS grid_title, model, type, url, last_modified, CONCAT_WS('_',id,model) AS solr_id, search_tag, bin_con AS text from aitiologikes_ektheseis where type = 'bin' and last_modified &gt; '${dataimporter.last_index_time}'"
    transformer="TemplateTransformer"
    dataSource="db">         
      <field column="id" name="ida" />               
      <field column="solr_id" name="solr_id" />
      <field column="title" name="title" stripHTML="true" />
      <field column="grid_title" name="grid_title" stripHTML="true" />
      <field column="model" name="model" stripHTML="true" />
      <field column="type" name="type" stripHTML="true" />
      <field column="url" name="url" stripHTML="true" />
      <field column="last_modified" name="last_modified" stripHTML="true"  />
      <field column="search_tag" name="search_tag" stripHTML="true" />

      <entity dataSource="fieldReader" processor="TikaEntityProcessor" dataField="aitiologikes_ektheseis_bin.text" format="text"> 
          <field column="text" name="contentbin" stripHTML="true" />
      </entity>

    </entity>

       ...
       ...
  </document> 

</dataConfig>
```

**A portion from schema.xml (the fieldTypes and filed definition):**

```
<fieldType name="text_ktimatologio" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">

<analyzer type="index">               
  <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="lang/stopwords_en.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true"/>
  <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>               
  <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="lang/stopwords_el.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true"/>
  <filter class="solr.GreekLowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.GreekStemFilterFactory"/>       
  <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
  <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer> 

<analyzer type="query">
  <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
  <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="lang/stopwords_en.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true"/>               
  <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="lang/stopwords_el.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true"/>               
  <filter class="solr.GreekLowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.GreekStemFilterFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
  <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>
</fieldType>

<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
<analyzer type="index">
  <charFilter class="solr.HTMLStripCharFilterFactory"/>
  <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>   
  <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>                               
  <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="lang/stopwords_el.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true"/>               
  <filter class="solr.GreekLowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.GreekStemFilterFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.HunspellStemFilterFactory" dictionary="dictionaries/el_GR.dic" affix="dictionaries/el_GR.aff" ignoreCase="true" />
</analyzer>

<analyzer type="query">
  <charFilter class="solr.HTMLStripCharFilterFactory"/>
  <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>   
  <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>                               
  <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="lang/stopwords_el.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true"/>               
  <filter class="solr.GreekLowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.GreekStemFilterFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.HunspellStemFilterFactory" dictionary="dictionaries/el_GR.dic" affix="dictionaries/el_GR.aff" ignoreCase="true" />
</analyzer>
</fieldType>

<fields>
  <field  name="ida" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
  <field  name="solr_id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/> 
  <field  name="title" type="text_ktimatologio" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <field  name="grid_title" type="text_ktimatologio" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <field  name="model" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
  <field  name="type" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <field  name="url" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <field  name="last_modified" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <field  name="search_tag" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <field  name="contentbin" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
  <field  name="content" type="text_ktimatologio" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>     
</fields>
```

I really need help on this!

With respect,

Tom

Greece

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to "index" a BLOB? Meaning you want to eventually be able to search it? I am not sure I understand your question correctly.

I am guessing that you would want to first convert your PDF or .doc using something like [Apache Tika in Solr](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtractingRequestHandler) and then let Solr index that for you. Also, if you want to have your users access the PDF or doc, the best place would be the DB and retrieve it from there?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11426784/how-to-index-blob-field-in-apache-solr-indexing is a related SO qn. You may also want to read http://searchhub.org/dev/2009/08/09/searching-rich-format-documents-stored-in-a-dbms/ mentioned in the answer there,  but I am guessing that PDFBox is already in Tika and this is all integrated into Solr now.

Comment: Yes you figured out right. I want to be able to search the indexed BLOBS. As for the link you provided, I cannot understand the example. Specifically the Maven part. How do I implement something like the example describes using only Solr? Thanks

Comment: I just gave that link for reference. Try: https://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtractingRequestHandler